# Java, Object Programming: get Methods returning 0 value

Tags: java, object

**Main Class**

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Shapes {

        static String shape;
        static String circleInput;
        static String c;
        static String r;
        static String t;
        static double radius;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Creation of all three shape objects
            Circle circleSolution = new Circle();
            Rectangle solution2 = new Rectangle(shape, r);
            Triangle solution3 = new Triangle(shape, t);

            String choice = "y";
                // Creation of a while loop which continues when 'choice' is 'y'
            while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                // Prompts user for a shape or the interger 1 to end the program.
            shape=
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter one of the following shapes:"
                    + " circle, rectangle or triangle.");
                    // Converts the String 'shape' into an interger
                if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
                    shape = c;
                    circleInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the radius.");
                    radius = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(circleInput));

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( 
                    null, "The area of the circle is " + circleSolution.getCircleArea(), "Results", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( 
                    null, "The perimeter of the circle is " + circleSolution.getCirclePerimeter(), "Results", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 
                }
                else if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("rectangle")) {
                    shape = r;
                    // Prompts user for pertinent data
                }
                else if(shape.equalsIgnoreCase("triangle")) {
                    shape = t;
                }
            }
```

**Circle Object Class**

```
public class Circle { 
    // Circle object created
    Shapes circle = new Shapes();
    // Defines variables used in class
    private static String shape;
    private static double radius;
    private static String circleInput;
    private static String c;
    // Constructor for circles, with arguments
    Circle() {
        shape = Shapes.shape;
        radius = Shapes.radius;
        circleInput = Shapes.circleInput;
        c = Shapes.c;
    }
     // Instance method used to return the shape
    public String getShape() {
        return shape;
    }
     // Instance method used to return the value of the circle's radius
    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    // Instance method used return the string, circleInput
    public String getCircleInput() {
        return circleInput;
    }
     // Instance method used to return the specific shape
    public String getC() {
       return c;
    }
    double getCircleArea() {
        double circleArea = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        return circleArea;
    }
    double getCirclePerimeter() {
        double circlePerimeter = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        return circlePerimeter; 
    }   
}
```

For both the Area and Perimeter of the circle, I am getting a result of 0.0. Obviously, this is not desired.

If you have any questions at all, please by all means ask.

Any and all help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: My magic ball is saying that you did some mistake ;)

Comment: Why do you use static fields?

Comment: how are you passing the value of radius. Either you have to take it via method params or re-define your constructor to take it.

Comment: `radius = Shapes.radius;` this one looks like the culprit. debug and check the value

Comment: At the time of creation of the Circle instance `Shapes.radius` is 0. if you change the static value afterwards the circle will not be updated. Either create the circle after you know the value or update the circle instance directly. A little more helpful than a magic ball i'm sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you aren't assigning the radius value in your `Circle` object instance. You get the input, parse it, and then call `getCircleArea()`.

It appears that you are trying to have the constructor of Circle use the static radius variable in your main class as the radius.

I'll not go into why this is bad (completely goes against OOP paradigm), but this won't work because you assign the static variable AFTER you have already created the object.

```
 if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
                    shape = c;
                    circleInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the radius.");
                    radius = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(circleInput));
                    circleInput.setRadius(radius); //DO THIS                        

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( 
                    null, "The area of the circle is " + circleSolution.getCircleArea(), "Results", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, basically rewritten the code to remove all static variables. However, still running into an issue. I created a setRadius method in my Circle Class, however, I am getting the error that it cannot find the symbol in my main method.                                       public double setRadius(double radius) {
        return radius;
    }

Comment: It should be `public void setRadius(double radius) { this.radius = radius; }` you are assigning a value to the class member `radius`, not retrieving it

Comment: Thank you so much! I really need to brush up on this and practice of course. It's working now :)

Comment: @Goddard It is your choice to select which answer you want to accept (By clicking the hollow tick). But you can only choose one. So you may want to accept the solution which helps you most.

Answer (score 0):

Static members of classes are default initialized

```
static double radius;
```

In this case `radius` is initialized to zero. And this is what is used to calculate Area and Perimeter.

An extra note : it's quite unusual to instantiate a class containing the main method of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several problems with your codes. Probably because you misunderstood the use of `static` and some Object Oriented concepts.

## Your problems:

1. Your constructor is empty. How do you expect the instantiated objects to have different properties when you only have a default constructor?

**Parameterize your constructor:**

If you are not using setters to set values of the object, you will at least need a parameterized constructor to construct objects:

```
// Constructor for circles, with arguments
Circle(double radius)
{
    radius = this.radius;
    //Your other variables such as c & circleInput variable is not supposed to be here    
}
```

2. Almost all of your objects' properties are declared as static. Static variables are "shared" by all the objects of the same class which means if you set the value, it will be reflected in all objects. (To be precise, static variables belongs to the class and not individual object.) It doesn't make any sense when you want each Circle to have their own radius, yet declare it as static.

**Remove all unnecessary static modifiers:**

```
class Circle{
    private double radius;
}

public class Shapes {
    private double radius;
}
```

3. By intuition, your Circle class should be a subclass of Shape and you did not extend it.

**Place your class under proper hierarchy:**

```
class Circle extends Shapes{
    //radius inherited from Shapes now
}

public class Shapes {
    private double radius;
}
```

4. You are mixing locally used variables such as `circleInput` with other instance variables such as radius. You are also writing you main method inside the your shape class with all their varaibles mixed up. Your school will probably want you to separate them.

**Write variables in where it should be declared:**

```
class ShapesRunner(){  //Have a designated class for testing
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String circleInput, c, r, t;
        //Your testing for the created shapes.
    }
}
```

> Java, Object Programming: get Methods returning 0 value

Ensure you set the radius of the circle using a setter (if you have one) or via its constructor.

**Example:**

```
//receive radius from input
circle c = new Circle(radius);
//print c's area and parameter
```

Comment: Thank you! Really informative and helpful. Definitely helped me sort of some horrible issues with my code.